# How to save values in vector in MATLAB and plot them?

Tags: matlab

I was trying in one hour to plot a graph in matlab but got stuck in the following :

```
n1=1; %konstant
n2=1.5; %konstant

theta1=0:90; % I define my degree values from 0 to 90 
theta2=asind(n1*sind(theta1))/n2; % Snell's law : I calculate the other angle values which are depending on the values of the theta1

% NOW I WANT TO CALCULATE THE Rparallell VALUES WHICH ARE DEPENDING ON TWO INPUTS(theta1 and theta2) 

%Here is my first attempt to calculate the Rparallell : it does not work
%because the size of Rparallell is 1 by 1

for i=1:length(theta1)

    for k=1:length(theta2)
    Rparallell=(((n2*cosd(theta1)-(n1*cosd(theta2))))/((n2*cosd(theta1))+(n1*cosd(theta2)))).^2;
    end

end

%Here is my second attempt to calculate the Rparallell : it does not work
%because the size of Rparallell is 1 by 1

for i=1:91
    Rparallell=(((n2*cosd(theta1(:,i))-(n1*cosd(theta2(:,i)))))/((n2*cosd(theta1(:,i)))+(n1*cosd(theta2(:,i))))).^2;
end
```

When I execute the code I get Rparallell as a 1 by 1 vector but that is not what I want .. I want Rparallell become a vector of 1 by 91 values ..

I even tried to insert `Rparallell=zeros(1,91)` but it did not help to make the Rparallell a vector of 1 by 91 values ..

I want to calculate the Rparallell value when the value of theta1 and its corresponding value of theta2 are calculated ..

How to correct the code so that Rparallell become a vector of  1 by 91 values ?

thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should help you

```
Rparallell=zeros(1,91)
for i=1:91
    Rparallell(i)=(((n2*cosd(theta1(:,i))-(n1*cosd(theta2(:,i)))))/((n2*cosd(theta1(:,i)))+(n1*cosd(theta2(:,i))))).^2;
end
```

`Rparallell(i)` accesses the i-th element of `Rparallell`, so every value is stored in a different element of this vector.

Comment: oh my dear God ,, I just missed the Rparallell(i) , I wrote it Rparallell instead .. Thank you very much for help .. God bless you :)

Comment: No problem! Cheers

Comment: excuse me one more question : I want to plot the value of theta1 when the      Rparallell is equal to zero ... I did like this but does not work , you know why? `for i=1:91
    Rparallell(i)=(((n2*cosd(theta1(:,i))-(n1*cosd(theta2(:,i)))))/((n2*cosd(theta1(:,i)))+(n1*cosd(theta2(:,i))))).^2;
    if Rparallell == 0
        disp(theta1)
    end
end`

Comment: It is not good to compare `double==integer`. If 'A` crosses 0 use `A(ii-1)*A(ii)<=0` to detect the point. You can also use `A>-0.001&&A<0.001`